# error in spring-security.xml for constructor arg error

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, sha, password-encryption

i m using spring security for my login page.in this in the database user password is stored using sha-password encoder.now i want to use the same in my spring-security.xml.i tried this

```
<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
 <constructor-arg value="256"/>
 </beans:bean>


    <authentication-manager>  
  <authentication-provider> 
    <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
  <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
          users-by-username-query=
            "select email,password, 'true' as enabled from user_login where email=? limit 1"
          authorities-by-username-query=
            "select email, role from user_roles where email =?  " />
      </authentication-provider>
      </authentication-manager>  
 </beans:beans>
```

i m getting error at

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'constructor-arg'.
    - Security namespace does not support decoration of element [constructor-arg]
    - Configuration problem: Security namespace does not support decoration of element.
```

anyone help me for this,please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `constructor-arg` element is not in the security namespace, but in the `beans` namespace. So in your case, use:

```xml
<beans:constructor-arg value="256"/>
```